# Upload a file asynchronously to S3 in Flask request

Tags: python, amazon-s3, flask, celery, boto3

I have a Flask API that uploads files. Currently I am working on scaling the application.

I have a scenario where a user uploads a large file - in that case, I save the file locally in the flask request and then kick off a celery task that then uploads it to S3 (and does other things).

My problem now is that the celery worker(s) will be running on multiple machines - so they won't be able to access the local filesystem of the Flask server. My solution is to simply upload to S3 in the Flask request. The issues is that large files (100MB) can take upwards of 30 seconds and that bogs down the flask server.

I am looking for either a solution on how to use boto3 to upload files asynch (with a callback) or perhaps a better design pattern. Or perhaps someway to pass the entire file to a celery task?

Comment: Will this work :- Run your Flask app in multiple servers, just like your celery workers. So, App 1 will save temporary data in Server 1, which Celery 1 will take care of. Same goes with other servers. You can use a load balancer to distribute traffic among your app instances.

Comment: you may store the file on your app server. then start the celery process that will copy the file from your app server to s3

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri - that was the first thing that came to mind, but I am trying to get my celery workers off of this server and onto separate machines that wouldn't have access to the flask's local file system.

I could create a second celery process that has to run on the same machine as the webserver, but that's some extra complexity I was hoping to avoid :-)

Comment: @xyres - My webserver is pretty lightweight and I was hoping on only have one instance of it. I would like an infinitely scaleable amount of celery workers on different boxes. as they do all the heavy lifting. What you suggest would indeed work, though.

Comment: @GeorgeB I think a Distributed File System (DFS) is what you need. Basically, it allows disk access over a network, so you can access disks from another servers. BTW, I answered a disk sharing question a while back, check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47729053/1925257) for a little bit more explanation.